# IValueConverter returning as object not value that is expected

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

I'm trying to convert a string on a label (or anything) to another string. This is for Icon fonts.

Converter

```
  [ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(string))]
    public class StringToIconConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string property = ((string)value).ToLower();
            switch (property)
            {
                case "maximize": return @"\e901";
                default return property;
            }
        }
         public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

      ...

   }
```

Then I've added it to my pages that need it

```
        <Helpers:StringToIconConverter x:Key="Icon" />
```

And this is how I'm setting it

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource NavButton}"
                        Tag="Document"
                        Command="{Binding GotoDataMatrixEnterCommand}">
    <Button.Content>
        <Label Content="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, 
                         Path=Tag,
                         Converter={StaticResource Icon}, 
                         UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" 
                         Tag="Document" />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

And what I'm getting is

`Windows.System.Control.Label` in its place. Am I not converting it properly, I'm not quite sure why it is not replacing the correct information. I've tried a few things, and reading up online though I'm stuck at the moment. Plus when I try to debug it doesn't work (it never hits the breakpoints)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60974926/1506454

Comment: your mistake is that {RelativeSource} extension should be used with *Relative*Source property of Binding, not just Source: `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=...}`

Comment: Alright I'll take a look and try it out I believe I tried that but probably not or something else was wrong at that time

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the Binding on Label.Content. You should use RelativeSource, not Source.

It should be:

```
RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}
```

Also, you have a syntactic error in the `switch` statement of `StringToIconConverter`: `default return property;` should be `default: return property;` (you're missing a colon).